# These expressions give different results, how can I filter out the error?

Tags: summation

```
Sum[E^(a x + b x) /. a -> 1 /. b -> -1, x]
Sum[E^(a x + b x), x] /. a -> 1 /. b -> -1
```

First one returns `x`, second one returns `ComplexInfinity`.

In my case the first one is wrong. How can I filter out the error if I receive as input the function under the sum, and it can be any function (the error affects multiple similar functions, this is just the simplest case)?

Also, I tried

`Sum[E^(a x + b x), x, GenerateConditions -> True]`

and it returns

`E^(a x + b x)/(-1 + E^(a + b))`

regardless of the `GenerateConditions` option, which is wrong for the case `a=-b`.

Comment: `Limit[Sum[E^(a x + b x), x], {a -> 1, b -> -1}]` evaluates to `Indeterminate`

Comment: Help says "Sum[f,i]
gives the indefinite sum Underscript[\[Sum], i]f."  With e^0=1 what to expect? To take the limit after summation is even more math nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

`Sum[E^(a x + b x) /. a -> 1 /. b -> -1, x]` is literally `Sum[1,x]`, which returns `x`, as it should. There is no error with this since you are taking the limit before applying Sum. Now, `Sum[E^(a x + b x), x]` evaluates to

$$\frac{e^{(a+b)x}}{e^{a+b}-1}\,,$$

but, as you noticed, this is only valid when $a+b\neq 0$, and, if $a+b=0$, the result should indeed be just $x$.

You can't just take $a\rightarrow 1$ and $b\rightarrow -1$ because the limit doesn't exist when $a+b\rightarrow 0$. If you evaluate the lateral limits (using, e.g., `Limit[expr/.a->0,b->0,Direction->"FromAbove"]` and FromBelow) you will see that it goes to $+\infty$ from above and to $-\infty$ from below.

In a more general case, you can flag the problem when it occurs with some function `expr`, then maybe solve the specific case by hand. You could flag it (and abort the computation if you want), for example, with

```
If[Limit[expr/.a->1,b->-1]===Indeterminate,Print["limit is indeterminate, resolve by hand"];Abort[]]
```

If you would be happy with $+\infty$ as an answer in the case above, you can evaluate `Limit[Sum[expr/.a->1,x],b->-1,Direction->"FromAbove"]`, then, if the limit exists, you will get it as the answer. If not, you will get the limit from above.

Comment: The problem is, the input expressions do not have $a$ and $b$ to test the limit and can be of any form, including absolutely different functions.

Comment: Honestly, maybe you should close this question and try writing a new one with a more general example where your problem happens or just more of your code. Then you could formulate the question more precisely to go in the direction you actually need.